# Outlook 2011 - how to disable auto correction?

Tags: macos, ms-office

How can I turn off the **Auto Correct feature** in Outlook 2011?

I was not able to find anything about that in the web.

**Edit:**

- Disabling all Auto Correcting in the Preferences as Buscar웃 suggested did not help.

Comment: is this Outlook 2011, and you are talking about two different functions. 1 is auto correct (spelling) 2 is the autocomplete the email address

Comment: @Buscar웃 i have edited my post, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Is it the autocorrect feature from Mac OS X or built-in Outlook?

Comment: @rob its the one from Outlook

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Auto Correct (spelling) is located in the Outlook Preferences.

Open the AutoCorrect and uncheck all.

Just in case we are talking about something else:

To turn off automatic spell checking, on the Edit menu, point to Spelling and Grammar, and then clear the check mark next to Check Spelling While Typing.

Comment: I have disabled all of them in the Preferencess, but it continues auto correcting

Comment: @FelixLahmer restart Outlook.

Comment: @rob did not help, it just keeps on making Dr. to Dry.

Comment: Make sure you uncheck all (two pages) then you need to restart Outlook for the change to take effect, or sometimes restart computer.

Comment: @FelixLahmer Please disable autocorrect from Mac itself and verify if your issue is solved.

Comment: @Rob I even tried this, but it only happens in Outlook.

Comment: woow thanks @Buscar웃 thank you thank you thank you! It was the Check Spelling while typing!

Comment: sometimes it helps formulating the question correctly, but we found the problem :)

Comment: hard to form a Question if you do not know what the heck is going on there ;) i am not using mac too much

Comment: as said at then we solved it and that is what counts, your question was on target, I am just waking up so that could be the cause :)

Answer (score 11):

Changing settings within Outlook didn't help. It appears that Apple has an overriding spell check, and when it's on, Outlook still automatically corrects words not in its dictionary, making them into embarassing spelling mistakes.

In my version of the Mac OS (10.9.4), the master switch is in:
   - system preferences
     - keyboard
       -text

Other versions of the Mac OS (Lion?) apparently have it in:
   - system preferences
      - Language & text
        - text

Thanks to answers.microsoft.com for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Wow, that is an evil setting.

Comment: @laurelnaiad - actually it's an awesome setting which I assume is poorly implemented on microsoft's part.  OSX should provide its spell check as a default, override'able via application settings.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 places:

1. Outlook > Preferences > Autocorrect: uncheck `Replace text as you type`
2. System Preferences > Keyboard > Text: uncheck `Correct spelling automatically`